# Converting string to hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, hash

I need to convert an string to hash so that i can use its "id" attribute.
I am getting this string due to following code in my .js.erb file:

```
$('#link_id').data('test', "<%= @record_obj.as_json %>");
```

I am getting string in following format:

```
"{&quot;id&quot;=&gt;166,&quot;first_name&quot;=&gt;James}"
```

I need to convert above string to hash so that i can access "id" of the object.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'raw' to get a clean output when using erb inside of javascript.

```
$('#link_id').data('test', JSON.parse(<%= raw @record_obj.as_json %>));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i do not need to replace the _&quot;_. I am getting it as `"{"id"=>189, "first_name"=>"James"}`, but as a string instead of hash. Could you please help me out over here?

Comment: I have updated the answer. The reason you are getting a string is because you had wrapped your @record_object in quotes 

`$('#link_id').data('test', "<%= @record_obj.as_json %>");`

I removed them and now you should get your raw JSON.

Please upvote and mark correct if deemed correct!

Comment: If i am not wrapping it in quotes its blocking my js.erb logic.

Comment: `$('#link_id').data('test', JSON.parse(<%= raw @record_obj.as_json %>));`

This will convert the JSON to a Javascript object, which should enable you to iterate through it.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. It is working. :) But i need to change `as_json` to `to_json`. Does that really matters?

Comment: as json will parse it as JSON and return while to_json will return JSON as string.. So I have updated the answer.. mark it as accepted please!

Answer (score 0):

Try use id directly

```
$('#link_id').data('test', "<%= @record_obj.id %>")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i need the entire record instead of only id. Only for now i need to access "id".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#link_id').data('test', <%= @record_obj.as_json.html_safe %>);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but got the error of in valid method 'html_safe'.